# How to check a timeperiod is overlapping another time period in java

Tags: java, time

How to check a time period is overlapping another time period in the same day.

For example,

1. 7:00AM to 10:30AM is overlapping 10:00AM to 11:30AM
2. 7:00AM to 10:30AM is overlapping 8:00AM to 9:00AM
3. 7:00AM to 10:30AM is overlapping 5:00AM to 8:00AM

Comment: We need more detail - it kind of depends on how you're storing your time period. Is it `java.time.Period`? In general, to check if two time periods overlap is simple - compare the start and end time of each.

Comment: I am not storing my time period. I want find the overlapping time . for example ( 7:00AM to 10:30AM is overlapping 10:00AM to 11:30AM ) this time is overlapping. Like this i got fifty pairs of time. so I want to validate that every single pair with another pair.

Comment: When I said "how you're storing it", I meant what is the data type? It affects possible answers (as Visionary mentions in his answer, this functionality is provided already if you're using Joda time). For all we know the periods could be strings of text "7:00am to 10:30am", which would need parsing. Or the times could be stored as a Java Date. Or a floating point values with 0.0 equal to the 1970-01-01 00:00 epoch.

Answer (score 53):

There is a simple solution, expressed here as a utility method:

```
public static boolean isOverlapping(Date start1, Date end1, Date start2, Date end2) {
    return start1.before(end2) && start2.before(end1);
}
```

This code requires there to be at least one millisecond to be shared between the two periods to return `true`.

If abutting time periods are considered to "overlap" (eg 10:00-10:30 and 10:30-11:00) the logic needs to be tweaked ever so slightly:

```
public static boolean isOverlapping(Date start1, Date end1, Date start2, Date end2) {
    return !start1.after(end2) && !start2.after(end1);
}
```

This logic more often comes up in database queries, but the same approach applies in any context.

Once you realise just how simple it is, you at first kick yourself, then you put it in the bank!

Comment: `before` (and `after`) means strictly before. Hence the period is not zero length: `start1.before(start1) == false`.

Comment: @JoopEggen I was wondering how long it would take for someone to remark about that. Although none of the examples cover that edge case, I have edited my answer to present an alternative, but no less elegant (nicer than yours :) ), solution that caters for abutting periods if they are to be considered as overlapping.

Comment: aha, a boolean expert; apologies for my `== false` then ;). Still the first solution seems most appropiate.

Answer (score 24):

## tl;dr

```
( startA.isBefore( stopB ) ) && ( stopA.isAfter( startB ) )
```

## `LocalTime`

If you really want to work with a generic time-of-day without the context of a date and time zone, use the [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class.

```
LocalTime startA = LocalTime.of( 7 , 0 );
LocalTime stopA = LocalTime.of( 10 , 30 );

LocalTime startB = LocalTime.of( 10 , 0 );
LocalTime stop2B = LocalTime.of( 11 , 30 );
```

Validate the data, being sure the ending is after the beginning (or equal). A briefer way of saying that is “beginning is not after ending”.

```
Boolean validA = ( ! startA.isAfter( stopA ) ) ;
Boolean validB = ( ! startB.isAfter( stop2B ) ) ;
```

Per [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43315879/642706) by [Meno Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2491410/meno-hochschild), using the Half-Open approach to defining a span of time where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*, we can use this logic:

> (StartA < EndB) and (EndA > StartB)

```
Boolean overlaps = ( 
    ( startA.isBefore( stopB ) ) 
    && 
    ( stopA.isAfter( startB ) ) 
) ;
```

Note that `LocalTime` is constrained to a single generic 24-hour day. The times cannot go past midnight, cannot wrap around into another. There are *no* other days to consider. Validate your inputs to verify the beginning time comes before the end, or they are equal (if that suits your business rules).

```
if( stopA.isBefore( startA ) ) { … handle error  } 

if( stopB.isBefore( startB ) ) { … handle error  }
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you want to test actual moments on the timeline, you must adjust these time-of-day objects into the context of dates and a time zone. Apply a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( today , startA , z);
```

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 6):

If interval is opened (for example, some process is not finished yet) and end date might be null:

```
public static boolean isOverlapping(Date start1, Date end1, Date start2, Date end2)
{
    return
            ((null == end2) || start1.before(end2)) &&
            ((null == end1) || start2.before(end1)) ;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

JOda Time has this [functionality baked in](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html#overlap%28org.joda.time.ReadableInterval%29). It's very well-built and on JSR route to replace the broken Java Calendar API. You should probably considering using it.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:

Here is the working method:

```
public boolean isOverlapping(Date start1, Date end1, Date start2, Date end2) {
    return start1.compareTo(end2) <= 0 && end1.compareTo(start2) >= 0;
}
```

And here is proof for everyone to try it:

```
@Test
public void isOverlapping_base() {
    Assert.assertTrue(isOverlapping(getDate(2014, 1, 1),
            getDate(2014, 3, 31), getDate(2014, 1, 2),
            getDate(2014, 4, 1)));
    
    Assert.assertTrue(isOverlapping(getDate(2014, 1, 2),
            getDate(2014, 4, 1), getDate(2014, 1, 1),
            getDate(2014, 3, 31)));
    
    Assert.assertTrue(isOverlapping(getDate(2014, 1, 1),
            getDate(2014, 4, 1), getDate(2014, 1, 2),
            getDate(2014, 3, 31)));
    
    Assert.assertTrue(isOverlapping(getDate(2014, 1, 2),
            getDate(2014, 3, 31), getDate(2014, 1, 1),
            getDate(2014, 4, 1)));
    
    Assert.assertFalse(isOverlapping(getDate(2014, 1, 1),
            getDate(2014, 1, 31), getDate(2014, 3, 1),
            getDate(2014, 3, 31)));
    
    Assert.assertFalse(isOverlapping(getDate(2014, 3, 1),
            getDate(2014, 3, 31), getDate(2014, 1, 1),
            getDate(2014, 1, 31)));
}

Date getDate(int year, int month, int date) {
    Calendar working = Calendar.getInstance();
    working.set(year, month - 1, date, 0, 0, 0); 
    working.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return working.getTime();
}
```