# How to check if time period is overlapping another time period irrespective of AM/PM

Tags: java, time

The following link: [How to check a timeperiod is overlapping another time period in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106670/how-to-check-a-timeperiod-is-overlapping-another-time-period-in-java) is helpful to check if a given timestamp overlaps with another timestamp.

However, this only works if the two timestamp are either in `AM` or `PM`. What I want to check is, if a given timestamp is overlapping another timestamp irrespective if it's in `AM` or `PM`.

For example:
If I have an `Array` of timestamps (in 24 hour format):

```
1:00 - 3:00

13:45 - 14:45

3:15 - 4:00.
```

The first two are technically overlapping since 13:45 - 14:45 falls between 1:00-3:00 (if converted into 12 hour format)

How do I check for the same? 
I want to essentially check if there is any overlap between the timestamps (+/- 30 mins)

Comment: So you just want to treat the times as if they are on an analog clock?

Comment: Yes. Just realized this is a much better analogy.

Comment: What's wrong with converting every PM time to AM and using one of the approaches in that post?

Comment: Do you have any memory constraints? You can just duplicate 12 hour formatted values with 24 hour correspondents and check overlapping ones?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the inputs? Could they be 11:45 - 12:45 and 23:15 - 00:30? If we knew that each interval falls within either 00:00 - 12:00 or 12:00 - 24:00, it would be simpler. Also do I understand correctly that an overlap of up to 29 minutes should count as no overlap??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assuming that each interval is within either AM or PM

I am assuming that each interval is either completely within AM (00:00 through 12) or PM (12:00 through 00). I didn’t understand what you meant by “(+/- 30 mins)”, so I have ignored that.

As an aside I consider this an artificial challenge. In the real world 2 AM and 2 PM are not the same, they just happen to have identical representations on a 12 hour clock. Just as a flag pole and a person from Poland are not the same even though they both have the representation “Pole”.

As Sweeper suggested in a comment I am converting each interval to AM (if it was in PM) before comapring.

```
    LocalTime begin1 = LocalTime.of(1, 0);
    LocalTime end1 = LocalTime.of(3, 0);
    LocalTime begin2 = LocalTime.of(13, 45);
    LocalTime end2 = LocalTime.of(14, 45);

    // Convert interval 1 to AM
    if (begin1.get(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY) == 1) { // PM
        begin1 = begin1.minusHours(12);
        end1 = end1.minusHours(12);
    }
    // validate
    if (end1.isBefore(begin1)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("end1 " + end1 + " must not be before begin1 " + begin1);
    }
    if (end1.isAfter(LocalTime.NOON)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Interval 1 must be completely within either AM or PM");
    }

    // Convert interval 2 to AM
    if (begin2.get(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY) == 1) {
        begin2 = begin2.minusHours(12);
        end2 = end2.minusHours(12);
    }
    // validate
    if (end2.isBefore(begin2)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("end2 " + end2 + " must not be before begin2 " + begin2);
    }
    if (end2.isAfter(LocalTime.NOON)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Interval 2 must be completely within either AM or PM");
    }

    if (end2.isAfter(begin1) && end1.isAfter(begin2)) {
        System.out.println("They overlap");
    } else {
        System.out.println("They do not overlap");
    }
```

Output from this code is:

> They overlap

Corner case: I am accepting an end time of 12:00 (noon) for an AM interval and of 00:00 for a PM interval. `LocalTime.minusHours()` has cyclic underflow, so subtracting 12 hours from 00:00 gives 12:00.

The code may be simpler and easier to find your way through if you define a `TimePeriod` class with fields for begin and end, a method for checking overlap and an auxiliary method for converting into AM.

### With no restrictions

Edit: Assuming that each interval can be any length from 0 (inclusive) to 24 hours (exclusive) and may cross 00:00, this is somewhat more complicated, but I couldn’t let the challenge rest.

Some observations:

1. If one interval is 12 hours or longer and the other has non-zero length, the two necessarily overlap.
2. If both intervals are shorter than 12 hours, then if they do not overlap, we can go (count) cyclically forward from `begin1` through `end1` and `begin2` to `end2` in the order given here and *either* not cross 12 o’clock *or* cross 12 once and end up before `begin1`. If this cycle doesn’t work, then the intervals must overlap somehow.

In code:

```
public static boolean overlaps(LocalTime begin1, LocalTime end1, LocalTime begin2, LocalTime end2) {
    if (begin1.equals(end1)) { // zero length, cannot overlap anything
        return false;
    }
    if (begin2.equals(end2)) {
        return false;
    }

    // If any interval is 12 hours or longer,
    // the other one is necessarily included, that is, overlaps
    if (is12HoursOrLonger(begin1, end1)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (is12HoursOrLonger(begin2, end2)) {
        return true;
    }

    // Convert all times to AM
    begin1 = toAm(begin1);
    end1 = toAm(end1);
    begin2 = toAm(begin2);
    end2 = toAm(end2);

    // For the two intervals *not* to overlap we must be able to go forward
    // from begin1 through end1 and begin2 to end2 in this order either
    // not crossing 12 or crossing 12 once and ending before or on begin1
    boolean crossed12OClock = false;
    if (end1.isBefore(begin1)) { // to go forward to end1 we are crossing 12 o’clock
        crossed12OClock = true;
    }
    if (begin2.isBefore(end1)) {
        if (crossed12OClock) {
            // crossing 12 for the second time;
            // intervals cannot be in non-overlapping order
            return true;
        }
        crossed12OClock = true;
    }
    if (end2.isBefore(begin2)) {
        if (crossed12OClock) {
            return true;
        }
        crossed12OClock = true;
    }
    if (crossed12OClock) {
        return end2.isAfter(begin1);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This method uses the following two auxiliary methods:

```
private static boolean is12HoursOrLonger(LocalTime begin, LocalTime end) {
    Duration length = Duration.between(begin, end);
    if (length.isNegative()) {
        length = length.plusDays(1);
    }
    return ! length.minusHours(12).isNegative();
}

private static LocalTime toAm(LocalTime time) {
    return time.with(ChronoField.AMPM_OF_DAY, 0);
}
```

Let’s try it out using the times from before:

```
    if (overlaps(begin1, end1, begin2, end2)) {
        System.out.println("They overlap");
    } else {
        System.out.println("They do not overlap");
    }
```

> They overlap

Since the code and the arguments are complicated, make sure to cover the methods thoroughly with unit tests.