# determine if two cyclic times overlap

Tags: android, kotlin, math, time, calendar

I have been stuck on checking overlapping times. My calendar implementation allows for cyclic or wrap-around time (so having start time after the End time is possible)

For example:
`startTime = 3:30PM`,
`EndTime = 3:29PM`,
`TimeDuration = 23 hours and 59 minutes`

Some of the answers I found online work when the End Time comes strictly after the start time. How can I fix this?
I am using this StackOverflow solution but it's not fully working: [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

In this picture, The two time ranges overlap, but my implantation doesn’t correctly identify it:
[overlapping times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kElh7.png)

Here is the debugging output, it should return True but it's not:
[debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DtkJ.png)

Comment: If you only need the time then millis from midnight should solve it, what API are you using for working with dates?

Comment: Split your durations that cross the midnight boundary into two durations and check each of them.

Comment: @cutiko I was working with java.sql.date and had issues with it. I am using GregorianCalendar currently

Comment: Similar: [How to check if time period is overlapping another time period irrespective of AM/PM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60131155/how-to-check-if-time-period-is-overlapping-another-time-period-irrespective-of-a). You may be able to adapt the latter half of my answer there.

Comment: Could you paste, at best all the information from your debugger, if that isn’t possible than at least your code *as text* into your question, please?

Comment: This is answerable as-is, but would benefit greatly from the code not being an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that this method does it.

```
public static boolean overlap(LocalTime start1, LocalTime end1, LocalTime start2, LocalTime end2) {
    if (start1.isAfter(end1)) { // interval 1 crosses midnight
        if (start2.isAfter(end2)) { // both intervals cross midnight, so they overlap at midnight
            return true;
        }
        // Swap the intervals so interval 1 does not cross midnight
        return overlap(start2, end2, start1, end1);
    }
    
    // Now we know that interval 1 cannot cross midnight
    if (start2.isAfter(end2)) { // Interval 2 crosses midnight
        return start2.isBefore(end1) || end2.isAfter(start1);
    } else { // None of the intervals crosses midnight
        return start2.isBefore(end1) && end2.isAfter(start1);
    }
}
```

For demonstration I am using the following utility method.

```
public static void demo(LocalTime start1, LocalTime end1, LocalTime start2, LocalTime end2) {
    System.out.format("Does %s - %s overlap with %s - %s? %b%n",
            start1, end1, start2, end2, overlap(start1, end1, start2, end2));
}
```

Let’s feed some data to the utility method:

```
    demo(LocalTime.of(15, 30), LocalTime.of(15, 29), LocalTime.of(17, 0), LocalTime.of(17, 30));
    demo(LocalTime.of(9, 30), LocalTime.of(10, 0), LocalTime.of(10, 0), LocalTime.of(10, 30));
    demo(LocalTime.of(9, 30), LocalTime.of(10, 0), LocalTime.of(23, 0), LocalTime.of(10, 0));
    demo(LocalTime.of(9, 30), LocalTime.of(10, 30), LocalTime.of(10, 0), LocalTime.of(11, 0));
    demo(LocalTime.of(6, 0), LocalTime.of(18, 30), LocalTime.of(18, 0), LocalTime.of(6, 30));
    demo(LocalTime.of(6, 0), LocalTime.of(18, 0), LocalTime.of(12, 0), LocalTime.of(13, 0));
    demo(LocalTime.of(10, 0), LocalTime.of(10, 30), LocalTime.of(10, 30), LocalTime.of(9, 30));
    demo(LocalTime.of(23, 0), LocalTime.of(23, 30), LocalTime.of(23, 0), LocalTime.of(0, 0));
    demo(LocalTime.of(23, 0), LocalTime.of(1, 0), LocalTime.of(23, 30), LocalTime.of(0, 30));
    demo(LocalTime.of(22, 30), LocalTime.of(1, 30), LocalTime.of(22, 0), LocalTime.of(1, 0));
    demo(LocalTime.of(22, 0), LocalTime.of(1, 0), LocalTime.of(22, 30), LocalTime.of(1, 30));
```

Output:

> ```
> Does 15:30 - 15:29 overlap with 17:00 - 17:30? true
> Does 09:30 - 10:00 overlap with 10:00 - 10:30? false
> Does 09:30 - 10:00 overlap with 23:00 - 10:00? true
> Does 09:30 - 10:30 overlap with 10:00 - 11:00? true
> Does 06:00 - 18:30 overlap with 18:00 - 06:30? true
> Does 06:00 - 18:00 overlap with 12:00 - 13:00? true
> Does 10:00 - 10:30 overlap with 10:30 - 09:30? false
> Does 23:00 - 23:30 overlap with 23:00 - 00:00? true
> Does 23:00 - 01:00 overlap with 23:30 - 00:30? true
> Does 22:30 - 01:30 overlap with 22:00 - 01:00? true
> Does 22:00 - 01:00 overlap with 22:30 - 01:30? true
> ```

I am using `LocalTime` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, as the obvious class for representing a time of day. The `Calendar` class that you used in your code is poorly designed and long outdated and not suited for a time of day only since it necessarily includes a date, which may disturb the comparisons, said without having checked whether this is the reason that your code didn’t give the expected result.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much Ole. Also thank you for suggesting LocalTime, it works really well.

This Time issue was killing me for a long time, I didn't ask on StackOverflow all this time because people downvote me a lot of times for asking questions, so I was really surprised to get lots of extensive answers. 

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

If you consider time alone, your set of intervals can fall within a 48 hours domain: The extreme would be 11:59:59PM to 11:59:58PM interval that would end at 23:59:58 the next day.

Essentially, that would map to 00:00 hrs to 48:00 hrs. The first thing I would do is convert AM/PM to military time. Add a check if the difference between end and start is negative, if so, I would add 24 hours to end time.

You are now left with finding the overlap.

Comment: Your worst case example works out to just under 24 hours.

Comment: @Tenfour04 What I mean to say is the domain of the time intervals span 48 hours. Updated my answer.